# InflateException and ClassNotFoundException causing the app to crash

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, inflate-exception

I'm creating an app where when the user selects a check the second activity is called. However, when the second activity is called my app crashes and the log cat shows an error on my paycheckactivity oncreate method.

First Activity

```
public class TableListActivity extends Activity {
private ListView mListView;
private TableListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_table_list);

    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mAdapter = new TableListAdapter(this, DataStore.CHECKS);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent = new Intent (TableListActivity.this, PayCheckActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(PayCheckActivity.Extra_check, arg2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.table_list, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);}}
```

Second Activity

```
public class PayCheckActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String Extra_check= "abc";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paycheck);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
03-06 21:51:11.275: D/dalvikvm(1108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 36K, 4% free 3135K/3244K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
03-06 21:51:11.285: I/dalvikvm-heap(1108): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.200MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-06 21:51:11.325: D/dalvikvm(1108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 3% free 4234K/4348K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
03-06 21:51:11.695: D/(1108): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7fc9f38, tid 1108
03-06 21:51:11.775: W/EGL_emulation(1108): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-06 21:51:11.805: D/OpenGLRenderer(1108): Enabling debug mode 0
03-06 21:51:14.175: D/AndroidRuntime(1108): Shutting down VM
03-06 21:51:14.175: W/dalvikvm(1108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a5fba8)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Process: edu.udallas.tableservice, PID: 1108
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.udallas.tableservice/edu.tableservice.PayCheckActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class br
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class br
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at edu.tableservice.PayCheckActivity.onCreate(PayCheckActivity.java:22)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 11 more
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.br" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/edu.udallas.tableservice-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/edu.udallas.tableservice-1, /system/lib]]
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
03-06 21:51:14.225: E/AndroidRuntime(1108):     ... 21 more
03-06 21:51:17.095: I/Process(1108): Sending signal. PID: 1108 SIG: 9
03-06 22:03:15.835: D/dalvikvm(1134): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 4% free 3135K/3248K, paused 89ms, total 91ms
03-06 22:03:15.845: I/dalvikvm-heap(1134): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.200MB for 1127536-byte allocation
03-06 22:03:15.885: D/dalvikvm(1134): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 3% free 4233K/4352K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
03-06 22:03:16.215: D/(1134): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7edd508, tid 1134
03-06 22:03:16.315: W/EGL_emulation(1134): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-06 22:03:16.335: D/OpenGLRenderer(1134): Enabling debug mode 0
03-06 22:03:17.795: D/AndroidRuntime(1134): Shutting down VM
03-06 22:03:17.795: W/dalvikvm(1134): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a5fba8)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): Process: edu.udallas.tableservice, PID: 1134
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{edu.udallas.tableservice/edu.tableservice.PayCheckActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class br
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class br
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at edu.tableservice.PayCheckActivity.onCreate(PayCheckActivity.java:22)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     ... 11 more
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.br" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/edu.udallas.tableservice-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/edu.udallas.tableservice-1, /system/lib]]
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
03-06 22:03:17.845: E/AndroidRuntime(1134):     ... 21 more
```

Comment: post your logcat error plz

Comment: As currently I don't see any problem with your `onCreate()` snippet, I want to confirm: have you registered the activity on the manifest? Edit: never mind, you have issue on your XML layout file. Post your `paycheck.xml` layout too.

Comment: Yes. This is my manifest

Comment: What's `activity_table_list.xml` look like? Any XML errors?

Comment: what is in line 22 `edu.tableservice.PayCheckActivity.onCreate(PayCheckActivity.java:22)` should be obvious

Comment: please post your xml code, as it's shows error on line 15 of your activity_table_list.xml file

Comment: There is no line 22 in my paycheck activity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here, you are getting two `Exception`s...

#`android.view.InflateException` : Its causing when you are trying to `inflate` your view/XML. Since you are using `CustomAdapter`, so you are inflating your list item's XML inside the `onCreateView()` method and that XML causing the problem...the `LogCat` indicating it directly as...

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class br
```

#`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` : Its causing since you are trying to put `HTML` tag `<br></br>` inside your XML which is not supported by `Android XML`. the `LogCat` clearly indicating that you are using that `<br>` tag by this message...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.br"
```

there has no view in android named `br`...so remove it from XML...your problem will be solved.

Comment: You are a life safer! Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it from you...then please, accept the answer.

Comment: Dont know how you got to know so many things without the xml. Nice work. :) +1

Comment: I have the same issue that an object cannot be found, but the object is there on the correct path..

Answer (score 1):

Mention the activity name in AndroidManifest.xml File under "application" tag, like mention below:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.TableListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.PayCheckActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

</application>
```

if still it shows error than please tell the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have copy pasted (like I do too:)) the onCreate for the PayCheckActivity and hence you are missing the **@Override** keyword there.

This onCreate() is no more the Activity overridden method and hence the error.

Just do this,

```
public class PayCheckActivity extends Activity{
    public static final String Extra_check= "abc";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.paycheck);
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Try overriding it completely. Delete the current onCreate and then do it. Also clean your project and run. Meantime post the layout file for PayCheckActivity.

Comment: since `onCreate()` method calling `super.onCreate()` then it will inherit all the functionality automatically from super class...So, `@Override` annotation will not make any change.